# Node Express.js set route as a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was wondering if there's a way to do this or if it can be done at all:

In express.js I've created a route:

```
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

This about works but I was wondering if it's possible to add a variable instead:

```
app.get('/' + myVariable, (req, res) => {

  // so then I can do with the res of myVariable:

  if (res = 'something') {
     // do something
  } else if (res = 'somethingelse') {
    // do something else
  }

  //or use SWITCH CASE ...

});
```

If there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with [Route paramerers](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters).

```
app.get('/:myVariable', (req, res) => {
  const myVariable = req.params.myVariable;

  if (myVariable = 'something') {
     // do something
  } else if (myVariable = 'somethingelse') {
    // do something else
  }
});
```